# POST form data to server using React.js and Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, post

---

### Introduction

I am just beginning in MERN Stack and am currently trying to POST data from a form located in RegisterModal.js to server.js

The index.html file gets its content from index.js which renders App.js and depending on the button clicked different components are rendered.
(This is what I understand)

One of them being RegisterModal.js, I am trying to post data from this form to server.js

The code for both files are located below and my project structure is as follows. (The rest of the code is located on github http://github.com/yenvanio/testapp)

---

### Error

The error I am getting is "Cannot post to /register" and the console gives me a error of not found.

---

### Project Structure

```
 - .idea
 - build
 - node_modules
 - public
   -  index.html
   -  server.js
 - src
   - components
      - AdminLoginModal.js
      - PopUp.js
      - RegisterModal.js
      - UserLoginModal.js
   - App.js
   - index.js
 - package.json
```

---

### Code

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var app = express();

var schema = new Schema({
    user: [
        {
            username: String,
            password: String,
            email: String,
        }
    ]

}, {
    collection: 'users'
});

var Model = mongoose.model('Model', schema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/register", function(request, response){
   var username = request.body.username;
   var password = request.body.password;
   var email = request.body.email;
   console.log("Post Received: %s %s %s", username, password, email);
});

var port = process.env.API_PORT || 3000;
// app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Running on port 3000")
})
```

RegisterModal.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class RegisterModal extends Component
{
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form method="post" action="/register">
                    Email Address:<br/>
                    <input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
                    Username:<br/>
                    <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
                    Password:<br/>
                    <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
                </form>
             </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RegisterModal;
```

Comment: Is it not logging on the server when you post? You need to send some sort of response in your endpoint, e.g. `response.send('posted!');`

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for responding, I have updated my post to include the error I am receiving. I hope it will be easier for you to help me now.

Comment: Hey Heroselohim, thanks for the tip. I will change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

Actually, I copy pasted it and I can run it without issue.

Are you sure that:

- You have restarted your node process (to include changes made to server.js)?
- The node process is listening on the same domain/port as the HTML page is loaded from?

Comment: Hey shambalambala, thanks for responding! I have restarted it to include the changes for sure. How do I ensure the node process is listening on the same domain/port as the HTML page? When I run "npm start" it is running on port 3000 and in the code I have set the port to 3000 as well. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Yenvanio Does the URL of the HTML page (the URL visible in your browser's address bar) start with `http://localhost:3000`? If not, that's probably your problem

Comment: Yes, they are both 3000. if you don't mind me asking how did you run it? I will try that method instead.

Comment: @Yenvanio I already had a running express application for a project of mine. I simply put the `app.post("/register", ...` block in my existing server code, and then I added the HTML block for the form in an existing HTML file in the same application. Loaded the page, submitted the form, it worked.

Comment: To test easily you can also do `curl -XPOST localhost:3000/register`

Comment: Sorry for the multiple questions, but where did you store the html file and the server file? I think the directories might be causing an issue (Not sure)?

Comment: It doesn't matter because your form action is "/register". The leading / indicates that you mean <hostname:port>/register, regardless of the current page's path

Comment: I see, thanks for the information. The curl solution worked for me, Thanks!