# POST to Express the data from React form

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

it's my third day learning React and I'm trying to get my registration form to post to Express (so that I can add the values to my MySQL database). I was able to fetch some static information and display it on the React side, so I know Express and React are connected.

The following is from file **users.js**, where I want to gather new registration information, and afterwards add it to MySQL so that I can fetch it later when the user logs in.

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/users', function(request, response){
    var email = request.body.email;
    var first = request.body.first;
    var last= request.body.last;
    var skills = request.body.skills;

    console.log(email, first, last, skills);
    res.send(email, first, last, skills);
})
```

The following is from **register.jsx**. I commented out the portion that I tried to use to push the values from the form to Express.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Col, Button, Checkbox, Form, ControlLabel, FormGroup, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './register.css'; 

export default class Register extends Component {

    // constructor(){
    //  super();
    //  this.state = {
    //      email: '',
    //      first: '',
    //      last: '',
    //      skills: ''
    //  };
    // }

    // onChange = (event) => {
    //  const state = this.state;
    //  state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    //  this.setState(state);
    // }

    // onSubmit = (event) => {
    //  event.preventDefault();
    //  const { email, first, last, skills } = this.state;

    //  // componentDidMount(){
    //  //  console.log('state mounted')
    //  //  // fetch('/users')
    //  //  // .then(res => res.json())

    //  // }
    //  // console.log(this.state)
    // }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form horizontal method="post" action="/users">
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={4}>
                        Email
                </Col>
                <Col sm={5}>
                        <FormControl type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalFirstName">
                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={4}>
                        First Name
                </Col>
                <Col sm={5}>
                        <FormControl type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first"/>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalLastName">
                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={4}>
                    Last Name
                </Col>
                <Col sm={5}>
                        <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalSkills">
                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={4}>
                    List your skills, each of them separated by a comma.
                </Col>
                <Col sm={5}>
                        <FormControl componentClass="textarea" placeholder="Skills" name="skills" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                    <Col smOffset={4} sm={10}>
                        <Checkbox>I agree to the Terms and Conditions of USUME.</Checkbox>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                 <FormGroup>
                    <Col smOffset={4} sm={10}>
                        <Button bsStyle='primary' type="submit">Register</Button>
                    </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            </Form>
        )
    }
}
```

I have been researching for about ten hours and have found minimal information about posting to Express, at least for my circumstance. Primarily, I have found how to get data from Express. I have tried several methods for trying to post the information and have gotten the message Cannot POST /users after each try.

I would at least like to get the data to console.log so that I can see that it's grabbing the information correctly. Do I need to use componentDidMount in conjunction with the post request in Express? If so, how? Are there any good resources on posting form data to Express (to be pushed to MySQL database)? Do I need to use ajax? Do you know of any good resources that can outline this process?

If you would like to see more code, or get more context, you can visit my repo here: https://github.com/falondarville/usume

**Select resources consulted:**

Traversy Media YouTube videos about linking Express with React

[Stack Overflow Question - Mongo Specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793637/post-form-data-to-server-using-react-js-and-express-js?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46799872/using-react-form-to-post-to-an-api)

[React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

[Github Repo for Similar Project](https://github.com/AvanthikaMeenakshi/uthiramapp)

[Blog Post - Submitting React Form Data](https://blog.stvmlbrn.com/2017/04/07/submitting-form-data-with-react.html)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example

```
submit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e.target)
    }
    render() {
        const {children} = this.props;
        return (<div>
            <form onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}>
              <input type="text" name="name"/>
              <input type="submit" value="regester"/>
            </form>
          </div>)
    }
```

in console you will find form component but need to handle form data manually.

i will suggest use redux and redux form to control on form.

https://github.com/bsmahala/react-redux-route-sass-login

Above link is example of reactjs with redux redux form